# how to disable submit button after submission in Yii

Tags: yii

I am new yii framework .Plz help me for how to disable submit button after submission in Yii framework. plz explain in view, controller, and model for this work

Comment: I was interested to this question, too. Why has been closed ? It's a good question from a newbie perspective, so, why to go on wildly closing question ... !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicaly Yii comes with jQuery as client side library so you should use a jQuery selector to select your button and disable it. If you are having trouble selecting it you should add an ID to it.

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save' ,array('id'=>'my_id')); ?>
```

after that you could use jQuery to disable the button

```
$('#my_id').attr("disabled", true);
```

you should place that code in the same view (all client side code should go in views) in a jQuery document ready function.

Like stated, this isn't really a yii related question.

Comment: actually it is, if you are using yii2 form and have client side validations on your form inputs